# Set up a mercurial server on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, mercurial, ssh

I am new to mercurial. Here the question is basic, but I am very confused after googling.

I am programming individually, I have my mercurial installed on local machine (ubuntu 11.04), it is working well. Now I would like to keep a repository on a server, such that I can push and pull whenever good for me. I would like to use SSH and prefer not using any web servers. Is it possible? I have installed the mercurial-server on the server, but what is next? How to setup a remote repository and how to push and pull codes? Help needed indeed. Thanks.

Comment: This _should_ probably be on Server Fault rather than Stackoverflow, but it is programming related (sort of). Damn the grey areas!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have various way to publish a Mercurial repository on a server. You can find detailed information on the dedicated wiki page: [Publishing Mercurial Repositories](http://mercurial-scm.org/wiki/PublishingRepositories)

In your case, since you want only have SSH access, the following steps should be enough:

1. Copy your actual local repository somewhere on your server (including your `.hg` directory). You can use [`scp`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_copy) for example.
2. Clone the copied repository back to your local machine:

   ```
   hg clone ssh://myhostname.com//path/to/directory
   ```
3. You can now push/pull from your server.

Obviously, you need SSH access to your server.

Also note the double `/` after the hostname, this is perfectly normal and you must put them both. The first one is to "terminate" the hostname part and the second one is to indicate that the path start at the root of the distant filesystem.

If you want to give access to other people, be sure to have a look at [How To Handle Multiple Committers](http://mercurial-scm.org/wiki/MultipleCommitters) to configure the access rights correctly.

Comment: Hi, krtek. I try your method and it did not work out. Then I try the following steps:
1. Copy all project files on the server;
2. SSH login to the server, create a repo using "hg init";
3. "hg clone" to the local machine. 
I do not know whether the problem is server specific or a common issue. If anyone knows the reason, please tell. Thanks.

Comment: Er, forgot to mention: following the steps from my last comment eliminates the error: "remote: abort: There is no Mercurial repository here (.hg not found)!"

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the `mercurial-server` package. It is a *third-party* tool to manage Mercurial repositories. You only need Mercurial and SSH on the server.

Then make sure the command

```
$ ssh server hg version
```

works. Then create a repository called test in your home directory and try cloning it with

```
$ hg clone ssh://server/test
```

You can setup SSH keys when the basics work, the wiki pages krtek linked to will help with that.

Comment: Oh, yuh, sometimes the name is misleading. "mercurial-server" sounds like something for the server. Thanks.