# How to set up Mercurial server on a subdomain?

Tags: ssh, dns, mercurial

Let's say I want to store my Mercurial repos on my server at `/var/repos/REPO_NAME`, but I'd like to [push/pull](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8416213/65387) this repo with `ssh://hg.example.org/REPO_NAME` instead of `ssh://hg.example.org//var/repos/REPO_NAME`. Can I do that?

i.e. I'd like to omit `/var/repos` from the path without having to put the repos in the root of my server.

Comment: Yes, you can. Just create user with different HOME, than  usual user

Comment: @LazyBadger Can you elaborate on that? Suppose I `usermod -d /home/hg hg` -- would the path then become `ssh://hg.example.org/REPO_NAME` ? And also, I can't SSH in without a password after changing the homedir.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "subdomain".

Comment: `hg.example.org`. `hg.` is the subdomain. Actually.. now that I think about it, the subdomain part is irrelevant to the question. What I actually want to know is if there's a way for me to not need to specify the full path; i.e. omit the `/var/repos` part. Not sure if this would be a Mercurial thing, or maybe just an SSH thing.

Comment: The description of this sounds like what I wanted: https://www.mankier.com/8/hg-ssh

Answer (score 0):

I found *a* solution. Not sure if this is the best one.

First, update `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to set the location of the `authorized_keys` for the user, because we're about to change their homedir and sshd won't be able to find it otherwise:

```
Match User hg
  AuthorizedKeysFile /home/hg/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Then change their homedir to where you wanted the quick access:

```
usermod -d /var/repos hg
```

You can verify it gets set in `cat /etc/passwd`.

Then restart `sshd` to make the changes take affect:

```
/etc/init.d/ssh restart
```

SSH in as your hg user to verify:

```
ssh hg@example.org
pwd # /var/repos
exit
```

Try cloning:

```
hg clone ssh://hg@example.org/your-repo
```

PS: I know this is a user, not a subdomain. I'm still figuring things out >.<

Answer (score 0):

Found another solution by combining [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/822554/28684) and [this article](https://research.kudelskisecurity.com/2013/05/14/restrict-ssh-logins-to-a-single-command/).

Simply edit the `authorized_keys` file:

```
nano /home/hg/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Prepend a command to `cd` into the directory of your choosing:

```
command="cd /var/repos && $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND" ssh-rsa AAAAB3...
```

The trick here is to use `$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND`. If you use `$SHELL` or `/bin/bash -l` like in those links, Mercurial won't like it:

```
mark@MARK-DESKTOP /tmp % hg clone ssh://hg@example.org/repo
remote: /bin/bash: line 1: hello: command not found
remote: /bin/bash: line 2: between: command not found
remote: /bin/bash: line 3: pairs: command not found
```

But with the above, it works great, and you don't have to change the homedir!

It actually has the side-effect of not letting you SSH in anymore:

```
mark@MARK-DESKTOP /tmp % ssh hg@example.org
Connection to example.org closed.
```

I think it just lets you execute that one command and then exits. But that's how Mercurial functions, so it works for this purpose.